# Next edittext when enter clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to implement a button that does not move to next edittext when clicked. So here is my code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/address_edittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="@string/address_textview_hint"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/search_button"
            android:imeOptions="actionNone"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

When I click this button some actions are done by code, but incorrectly jumps to other edittext.

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` here is [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)

see this `example`

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emai_text);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

      @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {

        // your action...........

        }
      return false;
     }
 });
```

Comment: What I want is not to move to next edittext when enter button is clicked in the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

just you need to add textMultiLine in addition to textCapWords

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_itemDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"  
  />
```